# Bootstrap 4 Button Group Responsive without adding custom css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a div with a button group.

Here is the code:

```
<div id="main"><!-- This is 100% width and no passing or margin -->

    <div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar">
      <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group">

      <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add</button>
      </div>

      <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> Import</button>
      </div>

      <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Delete</button>
      </div>

      <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"><i class="fa fa-save"></i> Save</button>
      </div>

      </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

This issue is that I need these buttons the:

```
1. Be the same size 
2. Take up 100% of the parent div inline
```

I can only fit 3 buttons at the moment but need to fix 4.

I could divide 100 by 4 and give the buttons the size, but as I'm using Bootstrap 4, is there a way to do this using Bootstrap's 4 own classes or if you can't do it just using bootstrap 4 classes, how can I best do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this in your index.html file

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<!-- Required meta tags -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRe3js3W69CrGF8kKXvvmYtT4zNGqicXRjvuAnmmbvPZXc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" type="text/css">
<title>WeGo</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="main"><!-- This is 100% width and no passing or margin -->

<div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar">
  <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified bg-primary" role="group" style="width: 100%;">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-3 btn-group" role="group">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" style="width: 20em;"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add</button>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-3 btn-group" role="group">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" style="width: 20em;"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> Import</button>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-3 btn-group" role="group">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" style="width: 20em;"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Delete</button>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-3 btn-group" role="group">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" style="width: 20em;"><i class="fa fa-save"></i> Save</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

</div>
<script src="jquery/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="popper/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Also there but there are spaces between buttons

Comment: It's padding...I left them to be aligned to the left with no padding outside the buttons